Integral curve of Morse function
If $X$ is a smooth vector field on a $n$-dim manifold $M$ , then in a co-ordinate chart $U$ ,  $X$ can be written as $X=\sum_{i=1} ^{n}a_{i}\frac {\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$ where $\forall i$, $a_{i}$ are smooth function defined on the co-ordinate chart $U$.
Suppose $f: M \to R$ be a smooth function . Define a vector field $X_f = \sum_{i=1} ^{n}\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_{i}} \frac {\partial }{\partial x_{i}}$. This vector field is called Gradient vector field of $f$. For a Morse function $f:M \to R$ , by Morse lemma there exists a co-ordinate neighbor of a critical point $p \in M$ , where $f$ has a form : $f(x_{1} , \ldots x_{n}) = -x_{1}^{2}- \ldots - x_{\lambda}^{2}+x_{\lambda + 1}^{2} + \ldots + x_{n}^{2}$ where $\lambda $ is the index of the critical point. So in this co-ordinate neighborhood $X_{f} = -2x_{1} \frac {\partial}{\partial x_{1} }-\ldots-2x_{\lambda}\frac {\partial}{\partial x_{\lambda}}+2x_{\lambda +1}\frac {\partial}{\partial x_{\lambda+1}}+\ldots+2x_{n}\frac {\partial}{\partial x_{n}}$ .
Now , if $X$ is a smooth vector field and $f:M \to R $ is a Morse function , then we call $X$ is a Gradient like vector field of $f$ if the following hold :
(1) $X . f > 0 $ away from the critical point;
(2) There exists a neighborhood $V$ for the critical point $p \in M$ , where $X=X_f$ .
"If $X$ is a gradient-like vector field of a Morse function $f:M \to R$, then the integral curve $ c_p(t) $ starting at an arbitrary point $p$ approaches critical points as $t \to +∞ $ and as $ t \to - ∞ $."
The above text is written in the book " An Introduction to Morse Theory " by Yukio Matsumoto (page number 66). Can any body help me please , why this is true?

The title makes no sense. What does “$X$ is a gradient-like vector field” of $f$ mean?

@TedShifrin I have just edited my question by defining Gradient like vector field .
